# Running Program for 60 minutes and Each Thread uses Different ID

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

How do I make sure each thread is using different unique ID and that ID should be in between startExistingRange and endExistingRange. As I am worried because the program is supposed to run for 60 minutes and before the 60 minutes it is possible that all the id's would have been used then what should I do. Should I reset the variables? What can be the best practice?

For Example:- Thread 1 will be using 25, Thread 2 will use 45 etc etc.

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;

    public ThreadTask(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + id);
    }
}

public class TestPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 10;
        int durationOfRun = 60;
        int startExistingRange = 1;
        int endExistingRange = 1000;

        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size); 

        // queue some tasks
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun*60*1000);

        // Running it for 60 minutes
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
/* I want each thread uses different unique ID between startExistingRange
 and endExistingRange */
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(What should I pass 
                 here so that each thread is using different ID));
        }

        // wait for termination        
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS); 
    }
}
```

Updated:-

```
public class TestingPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int size = 10;
        int durationOfRun = 1;
        IdPool idPool = new IdPool();   
        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size); 

        // queue some tasks
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun * 60 * 1000L);

        // Getting and releasing id in while loop
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
            Integer id = idPool.getId();
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(idPool, id));
            idPool.releaseId(id);
        }

        // wait for termination        
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS); 
    }

}

class IdPool {
    private final LinkedList<Integer> availableIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public IdPool() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            availableIds.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(availableIds);
    }

    public synchronized Integer getId() {
        return availableIds.removeFirst();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseId(Integer id) {
        availableIds.add(id);
    }
}


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private IdPool idPool;
    private int kk;

    public ThreadTask(IdPool idPool, int s) {
        this.idPool = idPool;
        this.kk = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        //Integer id = idPool.getId();
        System.out.println("Task " + kk);
        //idPool.releaseId(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing an ID to your task at creation time, have your task get their ID from a pool of available IDs. Since you have 10 threads, you only need 10 IDs. Each task takes an ID from the pool at startup, and releases it to the pool when done. Of course, the pool needs to be thread safe:

```
public class IdPool {
    private final LinkedList<Integer> availableIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public IdPool() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            availableIds.add(i);
        }
    }

    public synchronized Integer getId() {
        return availabeIds.removeFirst();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseId(Integer id) {
        availableIds.add(id);
    }
}


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private IdPool idPool;

    public ThreadTask(IdPool idPool) {
        this.idPool = idPool;
    }

    public void run() {
        Integer id = idPool.getId();
        System.out.println("Task " + id);
        idPool.releaseId(id);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int size = 10;
        int durationOfRun = 60;
        IdPool idPool = new IdPool();   
        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size); 

        // queue some tasks
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun * 60 * 1000L);

        // Running it for 60 minutes
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(idPool));
        }

        // wait for termination        
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you are saying, If I have 1000 ids then I need 1000 threads, so that each can use one unique id between that range? It is not possible that each thread can use multiple unique id's in between that range? Can you give one example based on my code? That will be of great help to me.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. You asked to find a way for each task among 10 concurrent tasks to use distinct IDs that are between 1 and 1000. I just said that since you only have 10 concurrent tasks, there is no need for more than 10 IDs. And each task could get its ID from a pool of available IDs.

Comment: But the problem I need more than 10 ID's and it can be more than 1000 also.

Comment: Either you accept to reuse an ID, or you don't. If you don't accept reuses, then you can't submit more than 1000 tasks. If you accept reuses, then 10 IDs are sufficient. But you may have a pool of 1000 IDs if you want to, and my strategy is still usable. You just need to get ID from the start of a list, and put back ID to the end of the list.

Comment: I think we need to reuse an ID I guess, Can you show me one example that will do the same thing you just said, basis on my code?

Comment: If you don't know what you need, then start by thinking about it and make up your mind. I'll edit my answer, but this is pretty easy stuff that you could figure out yourself.

Comment: I edited your code by adding my changes, so it should be something like this?

Comment: Yes. I removed the unnecessary variables, fixed indentation, and use proper typing for the milliseconds computation.

Comment: Thanks, So durationOfRun should be int or long in this case? I guess it should be long?

Comment: I have one more question JB, instead of getting id and releasing id in run method if I do that same thing in the while loop, then that is fine or not? I have updated my question by posting the code in which I am getting id and releasing id in while loop inside java main.

Comment: Of course not. If you submit 2000 tasks in a loop, there won't be any available ID after the 1000th one. This technique works because you have less than 1000 threads in your thread pool, which means that there will always be available IDs in the pool.

Comment: I don't think so I understand what you just said. So that means the way I did in the while loop is not right. It should always be in run method? Can you explain little bit more.

Comment: No, it's not right. You're submitting millions and millions of tasks to your thread pool. As many as it's possible to create in 60 minutes. And for each task, you're getting an ID from a pool which only has 1000 available IDs. At the 1001th task, the pool will throw a NoSuchElementException because the list will be empty.

Comment: I ran my same code by putting them in the while loop, it is not throwing any such exception. I ran it for one minute and I didn't got any such exceptions, its just that it is using id's and after 1000 it is reusing id again.

Comment: My bad. By releasing the ID just after you submitted the task, instead of releasing it when the task is completed, you just submit millions of tasks with IDs going from 1 to 1000, and starting at 1 again, etc. But this doesn't prevent several concurrent tasks to have the same ID. For example, if the first task is very long, and the 999 others are very short, the 1001th one will run with ID 1, while the first one (with ID 1 also) is till running.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of which IDs are already used in a set (and another for not-used ones for convenience).

Then you could start the IDs from 1 to 1000.  When you run out, you look for values that are available in the not-used set

Every time you start a thread, you move that id from the not-used set to the used one, every time a thread finishes, you do the opposite.

It is not possible that to run out of IDs as you only have a maximum of 10 threads running at the same time

Comment: So basically you are saying, If I have 1000 ids then I need 1000 threads, so that each can use one unique id between that range? It is not possible that each thread can use multiple unique id's in between that range? Can you give me one example based on my code?

Comment: You don't need 1000 threads, just wait until one finishes when you run out of threads and start that one again with a new ID

Comment: Can you show me one example? That will be of great help to me. And also in this Pool needs to be thread safe right? The only concern that I have as I am running for 60 minutes, so in that minutes it is quite possible that all the id's have been used right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Thread.getID()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29).

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, **this thread ID may be reused**.

Note my emphasis.

You could then add 100,000 * `the number of seconds you have been running` or something.

**Added** - by popular demand:

```
public void run() {
  Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
  // Name me from my ID.
  me.setName("X-" + me.getId());
  ...
```

Comment: I don't know about Thread.getID(). Can you show me one example?